# SSL Mixed Content issue in secure pages

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl, secure

I have set the `secure_base_url` to `https`and also have set `Use Secure URLs in Frontend` to `yes.` Still when i navigate the site i get warnings such as

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite/customer/account/index/' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://mysite/checkout/cart/updatePost/'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.
```

When i change the `unsecure_base_url`to https the site works perfectly without any warnings. Still i don't want to secure all the pages of the site by changing the `unsecure_base_url`to `https`. I want to set certain pages secure (by setting only the `secure_base_url` to `https`) without SSL mixed content. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: the problem maybe your custom theme or cache

Comment: @MagenX i don't want to make my whole site secure. I just want to make certain pages secure (by setting only the secure_base_url to https) without SSL mixed content.

Comment: exactly, customer page is secure, but code to /checkout/cart/ is not secure. you have to check that part of the page/theme etc

Comment: it has used `$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it using the first answer of this
[Use secure urls on front end breaks ajax loading into cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31770/use-secure-urls-on-front-end-breaks-ajax-loading-into-cart)

my url was `$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost')`.

Replaced it with `$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost', array('_forced_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()));` and it started working fine